# Comparing and matching 2 tables

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I was comparing and matching 2 tables on access database.

```
Table1.column1  Table1.column2
111            111
111            112
112            112
113            112
113            113
113            113
```

It's output on another table should be like this:

```
Table2.column1  Table2.column2
111             111
111             (NULL)
112             112
(NULL)          112
(NULL)          112
113             113
113             113
113             (NULL)
```

How should I do this? Insert into with cast but no good.

Comment: It isn't clear from your example exactly what you require, but you could look up `FULL OUTER JOIN` and see if that's any help.

Comment: Yeah, you might try explaining what you're actually trying to achieve.  Examples are great but not enough on their own.  There are all sorts of things that could produce that output in that specific case but would not produce the correct output in other cases.  ALWAYS explain the rules first and then provide an example that implements those rules if appropriate.

Comment: I'm using MS ACCESS so FULL OUTER JOIN isn't possible. But I'm seeing other alternatives. I think FULL OUTER JOIN is the one I'm working on, I'm gonna post the code as soon as I'm done. Thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you could do it with a union. But your example might not show all the different cases.

```
select column1, column2 from Table1 where column1 = column2
union all
select column1, null from Table1 where column1 <> column2
union all
select null, column2 from Table1 where column1 <> column2
```

The case I'm not sure is what happens if you have

```
111 113
113 114
```

With the query I gave you, it will return

```
111 null
null 113
113 null
null 114
```